# How to get values from database from current date to last 5 days

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

Get the values from database dynamically. Here is my database

[image: Database Image]

And Here is my code

```
<form method="post" action="" align="center" style="margin-top:50px;">
<select id="date" name="date">
<option>Last 6 days</option>
<option>Last 2 days</option>
</select><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
    $db=mysql_select_db("date");
    $sql="select value from sort";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['value'];
    }
}
?>
```

I want when i click on last 6 days shows current date to last 6 days values and when i click on last 4 days shows current date to last 4 days values. How to solve dynamically.

Comment: First store dates using a date data type. Then get back to us.

Comment: A good start would be to update from your `mysql_` extension to `mysqli_` or `PDO`  ;-) nah but srsly

Comment: It's working fine. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"select value from sort where  (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date)<=6)"`  or

```
"select value from sort where  (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date)<=4)"
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query to get rows assuming date_col is the column name in your table which contains date

```
SELECT col1,col2,.. FROM table_name WHERE `date_col` 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```